# Determine the points in the boundary of a given region in 2D

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, computational-geometry

What is a good way to determine the points in the boundary of a given region in 2D?

**Suppose that you are given a nested list with lists of two coordinates**, e.g.

```
     { {x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, {x3,y3} }
```

Of course the actual nested list would have a lot more points than 3, which are associated to a given region in the plane. **The nested list, for example, could determine a disk in the plane. Then, the output should be a nested list corresponding to a circle.**

I don't want any image recognition stuff applied to a possible plot. I would like operations on the nested list.

Comment: Is there any reason convex hull algorithms won't work?  What about concave hull algorithms?

Answer (score 3):

**This answer is based on @andand comment. The credit is all his.**

If I have a nested list called "region", with lists of the 2d coordinates, I would get the "convex hull" of it writing

```
    Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
    regionhull = ConvexHull[ region ]
```

But "ConvexHull" gives us the indices of the lists within the nested list, in counterclockwise order, corresponding to the convex boundary of the region. Thus, an adittional step is needed, to make the needed output:

```
    regionboundary = region[[ regionhull ]]
```

But still, this answer is incomplete. It seems to me that a "concave hull" algorithm would be the more general solution. Would anyone know anything about the concave hull in Mathematica? I may post an additional question for that.

Below, I show a figure to understand the concave and convex hull algorithms extracted from

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/concave-hull-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions

[image]

A tutorial for the "Computational Geometry Package" is found at

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ComputationalGeometry/tutorial/ComputationalGeometry.html

** **Addendum** **

**The package "alphahull" can solve the problem of finding the boundary of a concave region. Its description is found here:**

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alphahull/vignettes/alphahull.pdf

Comment: The package alphahull in the repository: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alphahull/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want some kind of interpolation technique. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation

Comment: I don't think interpolation has anything to do with it.